# Is svn network protocol part of Tortoise?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, network-protocols

I had `Tortoise` installed but decided to start using `SlikSVN` just a few days after. The Tortoise installation was left on the system. While revising my installed packages (on `Windows 7`), I decided to uninstall Tortoise.

Immediately after, my SlikSVN commands stopped being able to connect to my remote repository. I checked my network connectivity and everything was fine. Then I noticed that the URL to the remote repo was using the protocol `svn+ssh://` and started suspecting that the svn protocol might be something inherent to Tortoise so that the protocol became unknown to the OS once Tortoise was uninstalled either by removing associated binaries or some networking configuration.

Make no mistake, once I reinstalled Tortoise, the connectivity to the remote repo using SlikSVN worked again.

My question is, **is the `svn` network protocol something inherent to Tortoise and is it possible to use `svn+ssh://` without having Tortoise installed?**

Comment: Tortoise and SlikSVN are both SVN clients.  If SVN was installed as part of the Tortoise installation then the uninstaller probably uninstalls it also.  If SlikSVN is installed while tortoise is already installed, I don't expect it would install SVN again (since it is already there).  Instead of re-installing tortoise I would have re-installed SlikSVN and that would have probably also restored the missing dependency.

Comment: actually, i thought the same thing and uninstalled both tortoise and slik. then i installed ONLY SLIK hoping it would install all the necessary drivers and config but it didn't.  the only way the protocol would work is when Tortoise was installed, even when just using Slik

Answer (score 2):

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6406676/david-cram) pointed out, both Tortise and Silk are SVN clients, and have their own SVN implementations. SVN is not something inherent to Tortise just like HTTP is not something inherent to Firefox.

Having said that, I can only assume that the issue with your setup is not with SVN itself, but with SSH. Apparently, SilkSVN has some issues with SSH on Windows ([link](https://blog.assarbad.net/20131226/sliksvn-slik-subversion-is-a-bit-painful-to-start-with-on-windows/), [link](https://wiki.dandascalescu.com/howtos/subversion/subversion_access_through_ssh_on_windows), [link](http://linlog.skepticats.com/entries/2010/10/SVN_SSH_SlikSVN_and_Cygwin.php)).